# Using the pow() function with integers in C

Tags: c

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int power, n = 3;
    power = pow(10, n - 1);
    printf("power is %d", power);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is 99. But it should be 100. This incident happens when it takes n=3, 5 or 8. Why?

Comment: I tried to copy your code so I could attempt this for myself, but all I got was an image. Include your code in your post.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code.

Answer (score 1):

Pow is a `double` function, not an `int`eger. As such, it has small rounding errors, and probably calculates 99.999999996375 or so. When you assign it to an `int`, you lose all data behind the decimal point.

Use doubles for your values, and print doubles (`”%lf”`), and it will work.

Comment: The reason `pow` does not return 100 in this case is not because it returns a `double`. It is because it was implemented poorly.